# Cannot run React-Native code in Android Studio emulator

Tags: react-native, android-studio, android-emulator

We are developing an application using React Native, and using Android Studio's emulation to test our builds. Since a week and a half, one of our developer cannot start the emulator in Android Studio on their Mac. They get the error: "No identifiers allowed directly after numeric literal". However, no one else on the team has this error and can run the emulator just fine. One difference between they and the rest of the team: They are on iOS, while the rest of the team is on Windows.
They tried:

- Checking the code to see if there's really a variable beginning with a number. There's none
- Running the project in iOS emulator through XCode and it's working fine
- Deleting the project and reinstall it
- Returning two months ago in the GIT project on a version that was working in the past
- Deleting node_modules folder and rerun npm install
- Running "Sync project with gradle files" in Android Studio
- Trying a simple project in Android Studio. It works
- Deleting all emulator on Android Studio and recreate them
- Uninstalling and reinstalling Android Studio

Any idea what to do to make the emulator works with our project?

[image: No identifiers allowed directly after numeric literal]

Comment: Does a new React Native app run? If so, the problem may be a dependency of the project, and you may have to eliminate each one as a suspect.  Are there any custom native libraries in your project?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Yes, a new React Native app runs fine.
That's true we added some dependencies lately, but we moved back to a commit where we are sure the app was running well but this time it didn't.
For the custom native libraries, no we don't have.